# How to disable related videos using Fotorama

Tags: javascript, video, fotorama

I would like to disable the related video thumbnails that appear inside YouTube's embedded video player by default. Outside of Fotorama this can be done by adding "&rel=0" to the end of the embed URL, but this doesn't work in the latest version of the Fotorama plugin. I also can't find a relevant option for this in the docs on the plugin's website.

I could patch the plugin myself and force this for all videos, but I'd much rather have an officially supported option so I don't have to fork the code and break my upgrade path in the future.

Any help or direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried asking Fotorama author?

Answer (score 0):

I have to combine the support of custom embed code with automatic fetching previews in future releases. But there is a workaround:

https://github.com/artpolikarpov/fotorama/issues/57#issuecomment-22583205

**UPD**

Done. Just update to 4.4.0: https://github.com/artpolikarpov/fotorama/releases/tag/4.4.0.

Fotorama will understand your additional params for YouTube and Vimeo links (like `&rel=0&vq=hd1080`).